# OpenSSL 1.1.1.d vs 1.1.1k issue

Tags: mysql, raspbian

I've done apt-get update and upgrade and the version of OpenSSL reported by Python3 is 1.1.1**d** 10 Sep 2019. The problem is my client host is running 1.1.1**k** 25 Mar 2021 and I'm getting a connection error (wrong SSL version).
... Updating libssl1.1 tells me that I'm at the latest version already, 1.1.1d.

... I suppose I should also ask if there is a way for Python to connect using 1.1.1k to a server that is using 1.1.1d? Along that tangent, I'm using Mysql.connector. I know the server and client are configured "correctly" because my client can connect when it runs on the same host as the database engine, which is MariaDb.

The exact error message is:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'trogdb:3306', system error: 1 [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1129)
```

This is the tcpdump, there is a 3 second delay between retries:

```
16:45:24.174046 ARP, Request who-has dbserver (b8:27:eb:71:99:00 (oui Unknown)) tell 192.168.12.33, length 28
16:45:24.174052 IP 192.168.12.33.51755 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [S], seq 152001190, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 1285434605 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
16:45:24.430503 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51755: Flags [S.], seq 3481602879, ack 152001191, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3680782024 ecr 1285434605,nop,wscale 7], length 0

16:45:24.430600 IP 192.168.12.33.51755 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 1285434859 ecr 3680782024], length 0
16:45:24.435750 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51755: Flags [P.], seq 1:104, ack 1, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 3680782073 ecr 1285434859], length 103
16:45:24.435803 IP 192.168.12.33.51755 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [.], ack 104, win 2057, options [nop,nop,TS val 1285434864 ecr 3680782073], length 0
16:45:24.436748 IP 192.168.12.33.51755 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [P.], seq 1:37, ack 104, win 2057, options [nop,nop,TS val 1285434865 ecr 3680782073], length 36
16:45:24.439981 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51755: Flags [.], ack 37, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 3680782079 ecr 1285434865], length 0
16:45:24.439981 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51755: Flags [P.], seq 104:130, ack 37, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 3680782079 ecr 1285434865], length 26
16:45:24.439982 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51755: Flags [F.], seq 130, ack 37, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 3680782079 ecr 1285434865], length 0
16:45:24.440004 IP 192.168.12.33.51755 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [P.], seq 37:141, ack 130, win 2056, options [nop,nop,TS val 1285434868 ecr 3680782079], length 104
16:45:24.440013 IP 192.168.12.33.51755 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [.], ack 131, win 2056, options [nop,nop,TS val 1285434868 ecr 3680782079], length 0
16:45:24.445929 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51755: Flags [R], seq 3481603010, win 0, length 0
16:45:24.445930 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51755: Flags [R], seq 3481603009, win 0, length 0
16:45:27.446093 IP 192.168.12.33.51756 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [S], seq 1750823761, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 2602561978 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
16:45:27.706430 IP 192.168.12.33.51756 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [S], seq 1750823761, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 2602562237 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
16:45:27.707181 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51756: Flags [S.], seq 416666955, ack 1750823762, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3680785302 ecr 2602561978,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:45:27.707210 IP 192.168.12.33.51756 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 2602562237 ecr 3680785302], length 0
16:45:27.711004 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51756: Flags [S.], seq 416666955, ack 1750823762, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3680785348 ecr 2602561978,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:45:27.711004 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51756: Flags [P.], seq 1:104, ack 1, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 3680785349 ecr 2602562237], length 103
16:45:27.711021 IP 192.168.12.33.51756 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 2602562241 ecr 3680785302], length 0
16:45:27.711029 IP 192.168.12.33.51756 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [.], ack 104, win 2057, options [nop,nop,TS val 2602562241 ecr 3680785349], length 0
16:45:27.711160 IP 192.168.12.33.51756 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [P.], seq 1:37, ack 104, win 2057, options [nop,nop,TS val 2602562241 ecr 3680785349], length 36
16:45:27.715488 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51756: Flags [.], ack 37, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 3680785354 ecr 2602562241], length 0
16:45:27.715506 IP 192.168.12.33.51756 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [P.], seq 37:141, ack 104, win 2057, options [nop,nop,TS val 2602562245 ecr 3680785354], length 104
16:45:27.716795 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51756: Flags [P.], seq 104:130, ack 37, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 3680785354 ecr 2602562241], length 26
16:45:27.716795 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51756: Flags [F.], seq 130, ack 37, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 3680785354 ecr 2602562241], length 0
16:45:27.716810 IP 192.168.12.33.51756 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [.], ack 130, win 2056, options [nop,nop,TS val 2602562246 ecr 3680785354], length 0
16:45:27.716819 IP 192.168.12.33.51756 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [.], ack 131, win 2056, options [nop,nop,TS val 2602562246 ecr 3680785354], length 0
16:45:27.719254 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51756: Flags [R], seq 416667059, win 0, length 0
16:45:27.720338 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51756: Flags [R], seq 416667085, win 0, length 0
16:45:27.720339 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51756: Flags [R], seq 416667086, win 0, length 0

3 seconds between retries

16:45:30.724896 IP 192.168.12.33.51757 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [S], seq 3599738548, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3758629911 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
16:45:30.985153 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51757: Flags [S.], seq 3278475863, ack 3599738549, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3680788605 ecr 3758629911,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:45:30.985229 IP 192.168.12.33.51757 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 3758630170 ecr 3680788605], length 0
16:45:30.995059 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51757: Flags [P.], seq 1:104, ack 1, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 3680788629 ecr 3758630170], length 103
16:45:30.995113 IP 192.168.12.33.51757 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [.], ack 104, win 2057, options [nop,nop,TS val 3758630179 ecr 3680788629], length 0
16:45:30.995428 IP 192.168.12.33.51757 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [P.], seq 1:37, ack 104, win 2057, options [nop,nop,TS val 3758630179 ecr 3680788629], length 36
16:45:31.003811 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51757: Flags [.], ack 37, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 3680788641 ecr 3758630179], length 0
16:45:31.003812 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51757: Flags [P.], seq 104:130, ack 37, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 3680788641 ecr 3758630179], length 26
16:45:31.003849 IP 192.168.12.33.51757 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [P.], seq 37:141, ack 130, win 2056, options [nop,nop,TS val 3758630187 ecr 3680788641], length 104
16:45:31.007156 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51757: Flags [F.], seq 130, ack 37, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 3680788641 ecr 3758630179], length 0
16:45:31.007193 IP 192.168.12.33.51757 > dbserver.mysql: Flags [.], ack 131, win 2056, options [nop,nop,TS val 3758630189 ecr 3680788641], length 0
16:45:31.013955 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51757: Flags [R], seq 3278475993, win 0, length 0
16:45:31.020450 IP dbserver.mysql > 192.168.12.33.51757: Flags [R], seq 3278475994, win 0, length 0
```

Comment: This certainly isn't a requirement of any SSL protocol -- plenty of servers don't use openSSL at all but they have to be interoperable.  I would dig a bit deeper on that error and exactly why it happens -- it **probably does not refer to the openSSL version, it applies to the available protocols**.  Eg., if you are configured to use anything less than TLS 1.0 (eg., SSLv3), you are bound to have problems.

Comment: @roaima The client is a python3 script using the mysql.connector.connect method, I'm not well versed in this area (obviously), so I don't know how to get your "ssh -v" equivalent.

Comment: When you run the client on the db-host, is it still doing TCP (and SSL/TLS) connection, or is it doing unix-socket connection? The mysql (or maria) commandline client does the latter, but I don't know for the python connector. In any case if you can't get tracing from the client program, get a network-level trace with wireshark, tcpdump, or similar (can limit to port 3306). (There is definitely no difference in TLS protocol support between d and k.)

Comment: @roaima - I cannot figure out how to get mysql.connector to generate debug output, sorry.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - I've added a tcp dump, it should cover the initial attempt and a retry.

Comment: I put wireshark first because it shows (and decodes) the data, which tcpdump doesn't by default; if you can't run wireshark better capture with `tcpdump -w` and move someplace you (or we) can, or at least use `tcpdump -X`. Also you didn't state versions, which _might_ matter although generally mysql/maria both tried to remain compatible at that level. Anyway, see non-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer yet, but a partial analysis:

Your non-data tcpdump shows after TCP handshake, server sends 104 bytes, client sends 37 bytes, server sends 26 bytes, client sends 104 bytes, and server FINs.

On the system I can most easily test, CentOS7.7 with mariadb5.5.26, I get:
server sends 86 bytes greeting
client sends 36 bytes login
client starts TLS handshake (289 bytes ClientHello) and it continues successfully followed by data

The first two match pretty closely. Your client 104 could be a ClientHello, although that's rather short for OpenSSL1.1.1 (even if it only does TLS1.0&1.1, as older versions of MySQL/Maria used). But the server 26 sent *before* that can't be a TLS response (and would be too short for ServerHello anyway) and **probably is some kind of error message which is not SSL/TLS at all** but which libssl tries to interpret and it looks like wrong version (this would also explain the server FIN-ing without any further data). Obtaining data in the trace could confirm both of those, and probably increase knowledge toward identifying the problem.

Also if you do a successful connection running locally on the dbhost and it is in fact over TLS, which you should be able to capture on the loopback interface, that would give a reference for comparison.